# What does a trait bound mean when it is added to itself?

Tags: rust, type-traits, type-bounds

In the Rust documentation, I see implementations like this one, from [Option](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html):

```
impl<T> Copy for Option<T> where T: Copy + Copy
```

What does the `Copy + Copy` bound mean? Is it just a documentation quirk?

Comment: The standard joke is: it means "*very* `Copy`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a [known and fixed issue in rustdoc](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/25022).